# SQL Injection in getHibernateTemplate().find()

Tags: java, hibernate

I was learning hibernate framework and wanted to know if SQL Injection was possible in the following code?

```
getHibernateTemplate().find("select name from users where city=?", new Object[] { u_city });
```

Is there a better way to do this? (in terms of security)

Comment: This looks pretty safe. Except if there is a quoting bug in `.find()`...

Comment: Why don't you try and see?

Comment: @JBNizet not sure what you meant. Do you want me to see if I can bypass the `find()` function and inject SQL queries?

Comment: If this wasn't safe, you could pass `'foo' or 1 = 1` as argument and it would return all the user names. If it's safe, it won't return anything because you don't have a city named `'foo' or 1 = 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way is safe and SQL injection cannot take place in this.

If you use as below there is a good chance for SQL injection

```
getHibernateTemplate().find("select name from users where city="+'Colombo');
```